# What is a concise and robust way to write these statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, undefined, ternary

I have an <iframe> that uses some variables that are set in an object literal in the parent document. These variables are optional; if they're set, I want to use their values, assigning them to a more succinct global variable; if not, I want to call the function error().

First of all, is this ternary operator statement valid and effective for what I want to do? Are there any potential traps here?

```
parent.settings.account ? var account = parent.settings.account : error();
```

Secondly, is there a more concise way to write that statement?

A few of these variables are optional, but if defined, have a range of acceptable values. What's a robust way to handle this? Something like this?

```
if (parent.settings.polling_interval && parent.settings.polling_interval >= 1000 && parent.settings.polling_interval <= 5000) {
    var polling_interval = parent.settings.polling_interval;
} else {
  var polling_interval = 3000; // default
}
```

Basically, if it's undefined or out of range, I want to use a default value.

Can I rely on just a conditional statement like:

```
if (parent.settings.polling_interval) { ... }
```

or do I need to check if it's undefined, like this?

```
if (typeof parent.settings.polling_interval !== 'undefined') { ... }
```

Is there something more robust and/or concise? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The error() function is just a dead-end; it spits out an error message and then leaves the script to terminate. It doesn't currently return anything. The idea there is that the script can't function without some of these variables (like parent.settings.account) being defined - there is no logical default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
parent.settings.account ? var account = parent.settings.account : error();
```

You meant to say:

```
var account = parent.settings.account ? parent.settings.account : error();
```

Or even:

```
var account = parent.settings.account || error();
```

Comment: provided error() returns something or account stays undefined.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! I've since developed a better understanding of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
var account = parent.settings.account;
if (!account)
    error();

if ((p = parent.settings.polling_interval) && p >= 1000 && p <= 5000) {
   ...
}

var polling_interval = (p = parent.settings.polling_interval) && p >= 1000 && p <= 5000 ? p : 3000;
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! This is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

[1]

```
parent.settings.account ? ( var account = parent.settings.account ) : error();
```

This will raise a SyntaxError since you can't define a variable in that manner.

If `error()` raises an Exception / throws an Error then you can do:

```
    if ( !parent.settings.account ) {
        error()
    }

// continue code
```

As previously stated you can also assign the variable to the property:

```
var account = parent.settings.account || error();
```

[2]

```
  var pollingInterval = parent.settings.polling_interval &&
 parent.settings.polling_interval >= 1000 &&
 parent.settings.polling_interval <= 5000 ?
 parent.settings.polling_interval : 3000;
```

[3] You can use `if ( parent.foo )` and if `foo` is undefined no strict error will be thrown but it will just equal undefined, assuming parent is always defined.

If settings is defined and polling_interval is not, same case. If you're sure the property is set and the settings object will exist, then you can use

```
if ( parent.settings.polling_interval ) { }
```

It would help stating what `error()` actually does.

Comment: meder, thanks very much for the feedback! That was very helpful. I added a comment to my original question to clarify the error() function.